# Nested Fields Text Field Values are not passed to the Controller In a Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm trying to create a form with the nested attributes are generated in a new tab. I've setup my model so that it accepts nested attributes, however when I submit the form any values I've set for text fields are passed in as blank, but the controller is passing the nested fields to the model.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x", "group"=>{"pilgrims_attributes"=>{"1399738268141"=>{"surname"=>"", "name"=>"", "middle"=>"", "aka"=>"", "prefix"=>"", "suffix"=>"", "nationality"=>"", "passport_number"=>"", "expiration(2i)"=>"5", "expiration(3i)"=>"10", "expiration(1i)"=>"2014", "date_of_birth(2i)"=>"5", "date_of_birth(3i)"=>"10", "date_of_birth(1i)"=>"2014", "accommodation"=>"", "roommate_id"=>"", "flight"=>"", "seat_id"=>"", "special_diet"=>"", "status"=>"Pilgrim"}}, "email"=>"", "telephone"=>"", "secondary_telephone"=>"", "address"=>"", "country_code"=>"", "state_code"=>"", "city"=>"", "zip"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Group", "trip_id"=>"1"}
```

So it seems to picking up that it needs to submit the fields, and it's passing in the defaults in the date_selects correctly, however the values I've entered into the text fields are just blank.

So currently I'm not using a fields_for block, but it doesn't seem like I need to since something is getting passed to the controller. If I do need to use a `fields_for` block where should I place it in the html markup?

The Code:

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@trip, @group] do |f| %>
   <ul id="infoTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="active"><a href="#pilgrim_info" data-toggle="tab">Pilgrims</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">Contact Info</a></li>
     <li><a href="#payments" data-toggle="tab">Payments</a></li>
   </ul>

<div class="tab-content">

   <div id="pilgrim_info" class="tab-pane active">
        <ul id="pilgrimTabs" class="nav nav-pills">
          <li><%= link_to_add_pilgrim_fields('+ Add Pilgrim', f, :pilgrims, :data => {:toggle => 'pill'}, :class => 'add-pilgrim') %></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
        </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="actions span12">
    <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to 'Cancel', trip_groups_path(@trip), :class => "btn" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a snippet of the html that's rendered after I've clicked the add pilgrim button:

```
<input id="group_pilgrims_attributes_1399739023635_surname" name="group[pilgrims_attributes][1399739023635][surname]" placeholder="Last Name" size="30" type="text">
```

The link_to helper

```
def link_to_add_pilgrim_fields(name, f, association, options = {})
   new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
   fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
     render(association.to_s , :f => builder)
   end
   link_to_function(name, "add_pilgrims_fields(this, \"#{association}\",  \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")", options)
 end
```

And the javascript function that adds the fields:

```
function add_pilgrims_fields(link, association, content) {
   var new_id = new Date().getTime();
   var regex = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
   var display_id = $(".nav-pills").children().length;
   $('.add-pilgrim').closest('li').after('<li><a href="#pilgrim'+ new_id +'" data-toggle="pill">New Pilgrim ' + display_id + '</a><span>x</span></li>');
   $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="pilgrim'+new_id+'">' + content.replace(regex, new_id) + '</div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript function was adding an extra bit of html. Because i had two elements with the class ".tab-content" it was appending it to both tab areas. When i submitted the form it was submitting the blank form, because both tabs generated had the same id.

I changed this line

```
$('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="pilgrim'+new_id+'">' + content.replace(regex, new_id) + '</div>');
```

}

to

$('traveller_form_tabs').append('' + content.replace(regex, new_id) + '');
}

and added an id to the tabs

```
<div id="pilgrim_info" class="tab-pane active">
    <ul id="pilgrimTabs" class="nav nav-pills">
      <li><%= link_to_add_pilgrim_fields('+ Add Pilgrim', f, :pilgrims, :data => {:toggle => 'pill'}, :class => 'add-pilgrim') %></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="traveller_form_tabs">
    </div>
```

It's now submitting the values that i enter in the fields.